# Stack Overflow logout from multiple domains?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I recently created a stackoverflow.com account. But when I try to logout, it tells me I'm also logging out from

```
askubuntu.com
mathoverflow.net
serverfault.com
stackapps.com
stackexchange.com
stackoverflow.com
superuser.com
```

I have never used all of these domains and I didn't even know some of them exist. Why am I being shown these on logout? It is very confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are all part of the stack exchange network which stack overflow is part of. That is a generic message to inform users that logging out of one stack exchange site will log them out of all of them. In the past when you logged out it used to be only on that site when it was changed the message was added to let the users know what was happening.

Now also as a note when you login to one site you are semi logged into all sites as the menu bar will still recognize you as logged in (for navigation and favorites) even if you are not signed up for a site.

Comment: Hmm... but it doesn't show **all** StackExchange sites, just some. Why am I semi-logged-in into these select sites only?

Comment: @mceo It shows the different stack exchange domains. Most of them are under stackexchange.com, however there are some that have there own domain which is why those are shown and not all are. The message is just showing which domains you may be logged out of.

Comment: I wonder why such a message is needed. It is very confusing especially if I haven't logged in to any of those.

Comment: @mceo So a user doesn't log out of one site such as stack overflow and wonder why they are logged out of another site such as super user.